# Execute Tmux with Golang Exec

Tags: go, tmux

I want to execute a tmux session using Golang. I'm able to compile and get an exit status 1.

```
cmd := exec.Command("tmux", "new", "-s", "foo")
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I want to start a session. At the very least, I want to get a more tangible error. Any docs to refer me to? I couldn't find much on the Tmux manual pages. I think I'm missing a command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to connect **tmux** to your terminal. Try to add these lines after **cmd** initialization:

```
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
```

**UPDATE**: link to the [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/MRExdJsmYg)

Comment: DUDE! Thank you. Why do I need and Stdin and and Stdout? I thought it was simple as executing the command `tmux`